# Add existing Google account without accepting Google Play agreement

Tags: google-account

I've received a new Samsung Galaxy S5.

I want to add my existing Google account to the phone, to be able to use Gmail and my calendar. However, when adding my account under Settings, the phone requires me to accept a bunch of legal agreements, including one about Google Play and its billing functions.

I don't want to be forced to accept a legal agreement concerning a service I don't intend to use just to access my email and calendar data.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made an account for that sole purpose of not wanting to give my information, if google wants to take it, I'll happily provide fake information. I knew I shouldnt have bought a smartphone, this was exactly what I wanted to avoid.
"btw, in order to use your phone, and get access to a bunch of things youll never ever want to use, we'll demand all your personal information, access to your phone and microphone (Samsung style) and synchronization of all gallery, but that will be all"

Comment: Indeed. These things should be sold with a warning: "WARNING: To be able to use this product even in the most basic way, you must accept 1,000 pages of arbitrary legal agreements subject to arbitrary changes."